# Orthogonal complement of the kernel of $u\in B(H, H')$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H,H'$ be Hilbert spaces and $u \in B(H,H')$. Let $u^\ast$ denote the adjoint.

I know (and can show) that $(\mathrm{im} u)^\bot = \ker u^\ast$.

From this I would deduce that $(\ker u^\ast)^\bot = \mathrm{im} u$. But instead,

$$ (\ker u^\ast)^\bot = \overline{\mathrm{im} u}$$

and it is not intuitive for me.

> How to (geometrically, if possible) see that $ (\ker u^\ast)^\bot =
>  \overline{\mathrm{im} u}$ and not $ (\ker u^\ast)^\bot = \mathrm{im}
>  u$?

Comment: The definition of $\bot$ makes it be an intersection of kernels. A kernel is closed.

Comment: $\overline{\text{im}u}=\text{im}u^{\perp\perp}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $X\subseteq H$, then $X^\perp$ is closed.

Let $\{y_n\}$ be any convergent sequence in $X^\perp$ with $y_n\to y$. Then for any $x\in X$,
$$\langle x,y\rangle=\langle x,y-y_n\rangle+\langle x,y_n\rangle=\langle x,y-y_n\rangle.$$
Applying Cauchy-Schwarz, this gives
$$|\langle x,y\rangle|\leq \|x\|\|y-y_n\|$$
which tends to zero since $y_n\to y$. Therefore $\langle x,y\rangle=0$ for all $x\in X$, so $y\in X^\perp$.

Edit: I must have misread the original question, as I thought you were only asking why $(\ker u^*)^\perp$ must be closed. At this point we know that $\overline{\text{ran } u}\subseteq (\ker u^*)^\perp$. To see the opposite inclusion, let $x\in (\text{ran } u)^\perp$. For any $y\in H$, we then have
$$0=\langle uy,x\rangle=\langle y,u^*x\rangle,$$
so $u^*x=0$ and therefore $(\text{ran } u)^\perp\subseteq \ker u^*$. Taking orthogonal complements gives
$$(\ker u^*)^\perp\subseteq (\text{ran } u)^{\perp\perp}=\overline{\text{ran } u}.$$
Thus $\overline{\text{ran } u}= (\ker u^*)^\perp$ as desired.

Comment: Thank you. I know that the orthogonal complement is always closed. But it doesn't give me any better intuition about why then the complement of the kernel should be the closure of the image (it only is an explanation for why this should be true, but not a geometric one)